# Google Spreadsheet Formula to show heading

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I have a Google Spreadsheet in which I am comparing projectors.  Basically it has formulas to divide the bulb life/cost and contrast ratio/cost.  Then it adds the total of the two and gives me a number.  Using the max function I can determine which is the largest number in the set, but I would like to know if there is any formula to select the column header at the top based on the number.

If the highest number is under an Epson 2000.  I want a formula to make it say Epson 2000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of the `INDIRECT` and `MATCH` functions.

In the last column of your table add the following formula in line with the data that you would like to determine the max of:

#### Google Spreadsheet

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS([Name_Row], MATCH(MAX([Data_Span]), [Data_Span], 0) + [Column_Offset]))
```

#### Excel

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS([Name_Row], MATCH(MAX([Data_Span]), [Data_Span]) + [Column_Offset]))
```

Where `[Name_Row]` is the index of the row where your projector names are (e.g. 1 if the projector names are in row 1), `[Data_Span]` is the span of values that you're trying to find the max of, and `[Column_Offset]` is the distance of your first data value from column A (e.g. 1 if your data starts in column B).

See picture [image: here].

Comment: So i tried to use this formula and thought i understood it, but can you take a look again and see if i did something wrong.


[link](http://i.imgur.com/A6Y5CoA.png)

Comment: @IsaacBrekke you should have mentioned that you were using google docs and **not** Excel. Google docs formulas are almost the same but not exactly. For this to work in google docs you need to add a third argument to the Match formula to tell it that the list is not sorted. The final formula would then be. `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS([Name_Row], MATCH(MAX([Data_Span]), [Data_Span], 0) + [Column_Offset]))`